# Jave, I am trying to save a binary search tree to a file and restore, so it would save the info even after program terminated

Tags: java

All i am trying to use call these two methods restore and save to obviously save a binary search tree to a file after an interface of ADD, DELETE, FIND... and process() is the method to process these operations. how ever I am trying to work on these two restore and save.

I am totally lost on how to implement this solution i found:

http://leetcode.com/2010/09/saving-binary-search-tree-to-file.html

```
                     private Menu() {
                Interface_1();
            // restore();
            process();
            // save();
               }


    private BinarySearchTree<Person, String> phoneBook;


     private void add(String takeName, String takePhone) {
            if (pBook.add(takeName, takePhone)) {
            System.out.println(String.format("add(%s, %s) Operation Succeded.",
                            takeName, takePhone));
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(String.format("add(%s, %s) Operation Failed.",
                    takeName, takePhone));
    }
}


           private void add(String takeName, String takePhone) {
    if (pBook.add(takeName, takePhone)) {
        System.out.println(String.format("add(%s, %s) Operation Succeded.",
                takeName, takePhone));
    } else {
        System.out.println(String.format("add(%s, %s) Operation Failed.",
                takeName, takePhone));
    }
}
```

Comment: http://leetcode.com/2010/09/serializationdeserialization-of-binary.html

Comment: that is for BinaryTree, i am working with a Binary Search Tree

Comment: Did you check the difference between BinaryTree and BinarySearchTree? Why do you think that the solution for one would not work for the other?

Comment: I just gave you pointer  you can develop your solution referring it.We are not here to spoon feed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pardon my understanding, but is the problem that you are facing is how to reconstruct your tree elsewhere? If it is so then you can use the Inorder and Postorder/Preorder traversals to save a tree in a file and then reconstruct it later. This is a generalized process and can be used for Binary Tree even, hence BST can be reconstructed the same way even.
For this, do the inorder and preorder traversal and save them to some file and then reconstruct. You can take a look at the following example for an idea about how to reconstruct

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-tree-from-given-inorder-and-preorder-traversal/

Hope it helps.

BR,
ShallOvercome.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but i am just confused. Like I have an add function for each node, how do i turn these nodes in to a tree.

Comment: Okay so what you are building is not a BST but sort of list as it has only add function. So first, you will have to design your approach as to what you want to do. I would suggest to give it sometime before starting to code. PS: Seems like you are creating a phonebook so rather than concentrating on BST, take a look at trie.